# Is it safe to remove write permission from postfix main.cf?

Tags: postfix

While I track down what facility is re/setting mydomain to "local" I'd like turn main.cf into a read-only permissioned file.  At present the permissions are 644, owned by root.

Is that safe to do?

This is an old (soon to be upgraded fully) Mac OS X 10.6.8 Server.  At 7:48am this morning mail was flowing fine.  I used the Server Admin.app GUI admin tool to do some log filtering and check on the mail database and then quit.  Shortly thereafter I sent mail to someone on the system and got a bounce message that the mail server does not offer relay services.  That's because it was receiving mail destined for username@ourdomain.ourtld, but by main.cf understanding, it should only accept mail for username@local.

A very quick fix, to be sure, but disconcerting that something (probably that really old Server Admin.app) would reset such important fields to default values.  But since I haven't been able to reproduce the change retracing my steps this morning I don't want to place blame prematurely.

Comment: What is your setup, scenario and concern?

Comment: See my additional paragraph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's safe, but.. remember that this doesn't solve your problem. 
First - if current permissions are 644, only root can write into this file. And even if you change it into 444 - root always can be able to write into this file. You can "force" remove by using chattr +i feature from extX, but - this is workaround.

Second - changing permissions doesn't show you what application/daemon change it.

I would recommend you using tool like auditd to "spy" into system and check what really change this file.

Comment: Though I haven't been able to get the problem to reoccur, my hope is that with the file "write-protected" the culprit with have enough issues with unexpected file status to write something into the system log that will give me evidence.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, it is

Postfix daemon will never need to writes `main.cf` when running. Write permission only needed when you edit it, either by preferred editor or `postconf` binary